# Increase the maximum number of javadoc warnings when compiling with Ant

Tags: eclipse, ant, java-8, javadoc, eclipse-mars

I recently upgraded my development environment from Java 7 to Java 8, which now finds a large number of previously-undetected *javadoc* issues.

By default, Ant (invoked via Eclipse Mars) limits its warnings (and I assume errors) to 100:

[image: Ant warnings limited to 100]

Is there any parameter to force Ant to display **all** *javadoc* warnings instead of limiting to 100?

I attempted to use the `-Xmaxwarns 1000` parameter via the `compilerarg` element, but it appears that the current Ant version in Eclipse Mars (Ant 1.9.4) [javadoc task](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/javadoc.html) does not support the `compilerarg` element (it is only supported in the [javac task](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/javac.html)):

```
<!-- Generate the API documentation. -->
<target name="javadoc" depends="clean" description="Generate the API documentation.">

    <!-- Create the build directory structure used by javadoc. -->
    <mkdir dir="${build.folder}" />
    <mkdir dir="${docs.folder}" />

    <!-- Run javadoc. -->

    <javadoc destdir="${docs.folder}/api" author="true" version="true" use="true" windowtitle="${documentation.title}">

        <compilerarg value="-Xmaxerrs 1000 -Xmaxwarns 1000" />

        <classpath>

        ...
```

[image: ant: javadoc doesn't support the nested "compilerarg" element.]

Java 8 `javadoc` *does* support these parameters (support was added in [Java 7 b100](http://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=6958836)):

```
C:\>javadoc -X
  -Xmaxerrs <number>               Set the maximum number of errors to print
  -Xmaxwarns <number>              Set the maximum number of warnings to print

Provided by standard doclet:
  -Xdocrootparent <url>            Replaces all appearances of @docRoot followed

                                   by /.. in doc comments with <url>
  -Xdoclint                        Enable recommended checks for problems in javadoc comments
  -Xdoclint:(all|none|[-]<group>)
        Enable or disable specific checks for problems in javadoc comments,
        where <group> is one of accessibility, html, missing, reference, or syntax.

These options are non-standard and subject to change without notice.
```

**Conclusion:** It appears that the Ant `javadoc` task is the limiting factor here, and if it supported the `compilerarg` flag, it would be possible to adjust the limit on errors and warnings.

Comment: Is it _ant_ or _javadoc_ limiting the warning count? Could you please run javadoc from the command line?

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose Ultimately, javadoc was limiting the warning messages to 100. I was looking for a way to control that when launching javadoc via Ant.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you noted, `-Xmaxwarns` affects how many warnings the `javadoc` program outputs.

`-Xmaxwarns` can be passed to the `javadoc` program with nested `<arg>` elements:

```
<javadoc ...>
    <arg value="-Xmaxwarns"/>
    <arg value="200"/>
</javadoc>
```

In my own test case, I was able to increase the reported warnings above 100:

```
[javadoc] Generating Javadoc
...
[javadoc] 112 warnings
```

Comment: This works perfectly. I wasn't aware that multiple args could be catenated that way in ant.